# Feast on this batch of duplicates

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions

As part of [my ongoing preaching T4 as a replacement for generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/c-sharp-generic-constraint-for-only-integers) I went through the linked questions and noticed there were plenty of them that were once closevoted but the votes dissapeared (due to a lack of enough votes, I assume).

Considering all the activity is located at this one main question I went ahead and added a closevote to every linked question that is a duplicate of this one.

I would appreciate if a moderator (or 4 kind souls) would cast the final vote(s). For your ease of use, here are all the selected questions:

- [Detect MaxValue of generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180674/detect-maxvalue-of-generic-parameter)
  (Possible not-duplicate! See for yourself first)
- <del>[C# generic constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391968/c-sharp-generic-constraints)</del>
- <del>[C# numeric base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375026/c-sharp-numeric-base-class)</del>
- <del>[Any elegant way to operate with generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694832/any-elegant-way-to-operate-with-generic-types)</del>
- <del>[Generic constraint to match numeric types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329576/generic-constraint-to-match-numeric-types)</del>
- <del>[Generics - where T is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267902/generics-where-t-is-a-number)</del>
- <del>[Creating a Math library using Generics in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63694/creating-a-math-library-using-generics-in-c-sharp)</del>
- <del>[Generic C# Code and the Plus Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039694/generic-c-sharp-code-and-the-plus-operator)</del>
- <del>[Less generic generics? A possible solution for arithmetic in C# generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449865/less-generic-generics-a-possible-solution-for-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-generics)</del>
- <del>[Constraints, generic variables and arithmetic operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254085/constraints-generic-variables-and-arithmetic-operators)</del>
- <del>[how to use where for operators at generics class c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758815/how-to-use-where-for-operators-at-generics-class-c)</del>
- <del>[Constraints on Type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683075/constraints-on-type-parameters)</del>
- <del>[Conversion on Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614258/conversion-on-generics)</del>
- <del>[How to add T and T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674330/how-to-add-t-and-t)</del>
- <del>[Check template type and perform respective computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148697/check-template-type-and-perform-respective-computation)</del>

Comment: I'm not sure if the fifth one ([C# generic constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391968/c-sharp-generic-constraints)) is a duplicate, it's not clear what OP wanted to do inside that function.

Comment: @Stijn: it isn't exactly about the same structs/classes but in the end it is about an arbitrary group of datatypes that don't have a common denominator that holds just those datatypes.

Comment: I'm not convinced [Detect MaxValue of generic parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180674/detect-maxvalue-of-generic-parameter) is a duplicate either.  This is one of those weird ones where the related question effectively addresses part of the problem but there may be other possible solutions unique to this specific situation (getting the MaxValue of an unknown numeric type).

Comment: @psubsee2003: it's not very prominent but there are two answers on that main question that address a `dynamic` solution. The core of the problem is addressed in that main question which moved me to consider it as a duplicate. I will remove my closevote because this could be seen as a more specific question whereas the main question is too general.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I understand that, and frankly if the question was closed, I would not vote to reopen because of how closely related the questions are, but the reason I won't vote to close is because the OP of the question I linked is asking for a specific response that can be solved in a manner that would not even be a valid answer on the possible duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All questions have been closed as a duplicate (with one more that was deemed to not be a duplicate).

I appreciate the effort put in.